# regular expression of numbers in ls in linux

Tags: regex, bash, ls

I have several files like aa_1.txt,aa_6.txt,aa_9801234123.txt,aa_90.txt
I tried to use

```
ll aa_[0-9]+.txt
```

to list them and order them as aa_1.txt,aa_6.txt,,aa_90.txt,aa_9801234123.txt. But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe `ll` through `egrep`:

```
ll | egrep "aa_[0-9]+.txt"
```

Comment: It does not work. There is no results after it.

Comment: @81235 change `grep` to `egrep`.

Comment: @Rashmirathi thx. Do I need to escape square brackets?

Comment: @Bohemian No, I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not show in order. I want it shown in order like aa_1.txt,aa_6.txt,,aa_90.txt ,aa_9801234123.txt

Comment: solved! I use `ll -v *.txt | egrep "aa_[0-9]+.txt"`